# Recurrence relation in series with parameter $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I was given a recurrence relation of this series:
$$a_{n+1} = k -a_n$$
$S_n$ is the sum of $n$ first terms of the series. So I was given that
$$S_{101} = 353$$
$$S_{199} = 696$$
**With this information I need to find $a_1$ and $k$.**

---

I found that if
$$a_{n+1} = k -a_n$$
Then
\begin{align}
\ a_{n+2} & = k - a_{n+1} \\
 & = k - (k-a_n) \\
\end{align}
So
$$a_{n+2} = a_n$$

I thought that I could find sums by thinking that the series above is an arithmetic progression, $d = 0$ but it didn't help. Later, I thought that it would be a geometric series, the ratio being $r=1$.

The sum of geometric series would be:
$$S_n = \frac{a_1(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$
Thus, $r$ can't be $1$.

Any help?

Comment: You are right, except that $r=-1$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why?

Comment: How did you conclude that $r=1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust because if it's always the same number then $a_1 * 1 = a_2$

Comment: Nope, $a_1\ne a_2$. What you have is $a_1=a_3$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, I got confused. I mean $a_1 * 1 = a_3$

Comment: What can you conclude ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached the conclusion that $a_n=a_{n+2}$.

Now all you have left is to solve the following system of two equations in two variables:

- $51a_1+50a_2=353$
- $100a_1+99a_2=696$

The solution is $a_1=3$ and $a_2=4$.

And then of course, $k=a_1+a_2=7$.

Comment: Oh... right! I thought I would need sum equations. Thanks.

Comment: @PichiWuana: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's just unroll the recurrence relation.

$ a_2 = k - a_1 $

$ a_3 = k - a_2 = k - (k - a_1) = a_1 $

$ a_4 = k - a_3 = k - a_1 = a_2 $

$ \cdots $

What do you find?

**All odd terms in the sequence is simply $ a_1 $**

**All even terms in the sequence is simply $ a_2 $**

The rest is trivial.

$ \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{101}a_i = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{51}a_{2i - 1} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{50}a_{2i} = 51a_1 + 50a_2 = 353 $

$ \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{199}a_i = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{100}a_{2i - 1} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{99}a_{2i} = 100a_1 + 99a_2 = 696 $

Solving, we get $ a_1 = 3 $ and $ a_2 = 4 $, so $ a_2 = k - a_1 \implies 4 = k - 3 \implies k = 7 $